# java.util.Iterator<java.lang.Object[]> cannot be converted to java.util.Iterator<T[]>

Tags: java, type-conversion

I am building a custom mod for Minecraft with an MCP (Mod coder pack). Setup my project and everything was working fine until I built the program and I got this error:

```
Error:(73, 35) java: incompatible types: java.util.Iterator<java.lang.Object[]> cannot be converted to java.util.Iterator<T[]>
```

Here is the full code:

```
public Iterator<T[]> iterator()
{
    return (Iterator<T[]>)(this.iterables.length <= 0 ? Collections.singletonList((Object[])Cartesian.createArray(this.clazz, 0)).iterator() : new Cartesian.Product.ProductIterator(this.clazz, this.iterables));
}
```

What is causing this error?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I assume you're referring to line 73 of https://github.com/nationgames10/minecraft/blob/master/src/main/java/net/minecraft/util/Cartesian.java - yes?   Not having Minecraft, I copied a cut-down version of this class, and this line compiles OK for me.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the line with this:

```
return (Iterator<T[]>)(this.iterables.length <= 0 ? Collections.singletonList((T[])Cartesian.createArray(this.clazz, 0)).iterator() : new Cartesian.Product.ProductIterator(this.clazz, this.iterables));
```

Comment: Spreading your answer over a few lines would make it much more readable.